# Wrapping std::thread for reuse as a class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I want my class to spawn two threads, that will run in a loop and interact with the owner class. This was easy, when I had my class with single thread at first: one atomic flag, one mutex etc. But as the requirement for second thread rose, I am thinking of some more elegant solution, that will encapsulate the thread and its utilities. Such as: a ThreadWrapper class, that could be instantiated in the owner class.

So far, I came up with the following, however I am not certain if this is the right way to go:

```
class ThreadWrapper
{
public:
    ThreadWrapper()
        : m_threadShouldRun(false)
        , m_threadRunning(false)
    {
    }
    ThreadWrapper(std::function<void()> fn)
        : m_threadShouldRun(true)
        , m_threadRunning(false)
        , m_threadFunction(fn)
    {
        m_threadPointer = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::thread([&] { this->threadLoop(); }));
    }

    virtual ~ThreadWrapper()
    {
        if (m_threadRunning)
        m_threadShouldRun = false;
        m_threadPointer->join();
        m_threadPointer = nullptr;
    }

private:
    void threadLoop()
    {
        m_threadRunning = true;

        while(m_threadShouldRun)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            m_threadFunction();
        }
        m_threadRunning = false;
    }

    std::function<void()> m_threadFunction = []{};
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> m_threadPointer;
    std::atomic<bool> m_threadShouldRun;
    std::atomic<bool> m_threadRunning;
};
```

Usage (fixed):

```
class Foo
{

    Foo()
    : t1(std::function<void()>(std::bind(&Foo::internalLoop1, this)))
    , t2(std::function<void()>(std::bind(&Foo::internalLoop2, this)))
    {
    }

    ThreadWrapper t1;
    ThreadWrapper t2;

    std::mutex mtx;

    void internalLoop1()
    {
        // looped task
        {
            std::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
            // write'n'read data to tx/rx queues
        }
    }

    void internalLoop2()
    {
        // looped task            
        {
            std::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
            // process the rx queue
        }
    }
};
```

This is somewhat similar to a Wrapper that I found [here](https://thispointer.com/c11-how-to-use-stdthread-as-a-member-variable-in-class/).
The shortcoming is that the sleep period needs to be passed to the ThreadWrapper object.

Is this a correct approach? Or maybe it should be done with a basis class and just inherited virtual method instead? As shown on the pic below.
[image: Thread model from codeproj.]

Source: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18383/A-thread-wrapper-class

Ideally I would like to use a template here, however the only "different" part between both ThreadWrapper is a single method, which rather suggests me inheritance/function pointers. Or am I wrong here?

EDIT: Motivation. In C# one could do the following: `var t1 = new Thread(() => internalLoop1());` In the end I am looking after such one-liner in my main class. Where the other ThreadWrapper class would take care of the thread safety management. Hence, being easily replicable if multiple threads were to be spawned.

Comment: I have difficulty imagining a scenario where `std::shared_ptr<std::thread>` is the right thing to use. Do you really want your wrapper to be copyable and share `std::thread` objects? Then what are those new instances of the other members used for? You'd have two instances of each of those flags, two function objects and one thread that uses one set of those members. And if the original is destroyed, the captured `this` is dangling. Seems like `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>` would be better. But at that point, you might as well just use an `std::thread` member directly instead.

Comment: You have a busyloop that does something then sleeps then loops.  Far less than 0.1% of threading code needs a busyloop, and it needs to be heavily justified.

Comment: I agree with @FrançoisAndrieux. Looks more like a XY-problem for me. Can you better explain in detail what you finally want to achieve/optimize?

Comment: `this->internalLoop1` is nonsense.  Lots of the rest of the code has typos.  Please post compiling code when trying to explain things whenever possible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yes, you are correct. It should've been unique_ptr. i.e. Thread not intended for copying.


πάνταῥεῖ:I want to spare myself the maintenance care of the boolean flags and thread.join() in the destructor. Doing it one time is ok and pure std::thread is enough in that case. But managing multiple threads in single class is cumbersome and I thought that encapsulation would be the solution.


Yakk-AdamNevraumont:Yes, Unfortunately I didn't label the "usage" part as pseudocode, because I had problems writing reasonable code. Which is misleading. I'm sorry. Hence I asked here.

Comment: Don't try to generalize the code too early… In practice, your solution would rarely be usable as most problem need specific solution. For example, you might need to start a thread at a specific point. And in properly written code, you almost never need a loop with a delay but you want to wait on some event.